# Unordered list "click" binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an unordered list where I'm trying to create a `click` binding for each of the list items.

How can I include list id and click binding?

```html
<ul>
    <li id ="tab1" data-bind="click: loadGeneralDataFromServer"><span data-bind='text:value'>General</span></li>

    <li id = "tab2" data-bind="click: loadWelfareDataFromServer"><span data-bind='text:value'>Welfare</span></li>
</ul>
```

How can I include id and click binding as one js that is using list id and another js that is using the click binding?

Comment: what exactly is the issue here?

Comment: syntax is wrong, can specify the id in the span?

Comment: what do you mean set the id of the span dynamically?

Comment: im getting error unable to parse bindings.. where am I going wrong

Comment: add the () to the click methods, `click: loadGeneralDataFromServer()`

Comment: Is this a dynamic list going of an ObserableArray?  I think you might need to go back over the tutorials.  You have different click bindings which I don't think can be easily set dynamically but the same 'value' binding to text on your spans so 'General' and 'Welfare' will both be overwritten with the 'value' property of your main view model.  Can you put a fiddle together on jsfiddle.net with a short sample of what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: @Nomad101 nope, that is wrong. Written that way knockout would call the function at binding time and expect *it* to return a function, which is then, in turn, bound to the click handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See "Note2" in the middle of [this page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html).  It explains how you can get access to the original event object that triggered the click inside your viewmodel.  From that event, you should be able to get the source element and it's id.

Here's a quick example:

```
<div id="div1" data-bind="click: clickDiv">Some div item</div>
<div id="div2" data-bind="click: clickDiv">another div</div>

var vm = {
    clickDiv: function(data, event) {
        alert(event.target.id);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psteele/e36Xy/)